# Очистка проекта при генерации debug или release

Tags: java, android-studio, android-gradle

В Андроид студио есть опция "Clean Project". 
Вопрос такой, возможно ли эти команды

```
> Task :usbserial:clean
> Task :app:clean
```

записать в build.gradle проекта, что бы они выполнялись автоматически при сборке apk?